# gets() without apology

Tags: debian, c, gcc

I use the gets() function a lot in my own programming.  I know that:

- the input string may overflow the allocated space
- in some environments, the above can be used to create an exploit
- that fgets() can be used instead to read standard input
- that the header declaration has been removed (from stdio.h?)
- that use of gets() is not recommended
- that gets() is deprecated

But I want to use it anyway; perhaps "saving" a copy of the headers and object code before it disappears altogether.

I don't like fgets() because if the input is too long, it just returns whatever will fit without any indication the string has been truncated.  The rest (or at least the next portion) of the string is returned on the next call, which is fine if you're simply writing a program to copy standard input to standard output or a file (why would anyone want to write a program to do that?) but useless if you're processing the data in some way.

Please don't answer the question how do I know the input string has been truncated by fgets()?  That is not the question I'm trying to answer.  The correct question is how do I use gets() without a lot of warnings of doom and disaster?

And please, no lectures about how I don't want to use gets().

I'm using gcc c under Debian 9; no IDE.

Comment: Just a friendly tip: when you try to preemptively argue against responses that people *might* have to your question, preemptively accuse people of “lecturing” you, and also don’t bother to clarify *why* those responses you predict and reject ahead of time don’t apply to you—all this just comes across as highly belligerent, even combative.  Don’t expect many strangers to remain willing to help you with this degree of belligerence up front.

Comment: I'm not trying to be belligerent.  I'm just trying to avoid off-topic *answers* that are of no help at all, or answer the wrong question (also known as XY-ing).

Comment: Progress report: I found gets() in /usr/include also with all sorts of fire-and-brimstone warnings against using it.  I copied the good parts to my source file.

Comment: So what you're saying is "I want to use something that's frowned upon (at best), but still, don't tell me what to do, I want to use it anyway". I suggest you read the manpages for the library functions involved (`gets()`, `fgets()` at least) and try to understand why `gets()` is not recommended.

Comment: What I'm saying is, I'm already aware of the arguments against gets() and yes, I want to continue using it.  And I'm sure the manpages will just talk about buffer overflows and stuff which I already mentioned in the OP.

Comment: What is the actual issue here? Too many compiler warnings? You have shown none of these. Also, if it's compiler warnings you're concerned about, can you say something about why you are concerned about these (presumably, you aren't compiling your code more often than actually running it)?

Comment: @Jennifer You don't like `fgets` because it truncates the string if it does not fit in the destination buffer, so `gets` is better, because it overruns the buffer instead? If you let this happen, you have a serious bug in your program, almost guaranteed to make your program malfunction, crash it, or make it vulnerable to exploits.

Comment: This question is a troll. Just close it and ignore it.

Comment: The ACTUAL issue is stated in the topic name: gets() without apology.  I want to use gets() and avoid all the warnings.  I am NOT trolling.  I have an issue and I'm trying to solve it.  I have NOT ever overrun the buffer -- so it doesn't matter if I use a depricated function, I just don't want to see the warnings.

Comment: The warning message is: "/home/user/src9/ProCheck.c:119:11: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘gets’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration] -- if ( !gets(g.workarea)) goto MAIN3;".  After I copied over the declaration (without the part that makes is not work without diddling with it), I got "warning: the `gets' function is dangerous and should not be used." (from the linker).

Comment: @Jennifer If you have never overrun the buffer, and don't expect to, then why are you worried about truncating the string when using `fgets`? It's the same thing.

Comment: I suppose it is but if I can avoid the gets() warnings that's what I want to do.

Comment: Can anybody tell me WHY my question was moved?  It happened in a Linux environment, after all.  I made that clear at the end of the OP.  And no, I don't want it moved to chat.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic => "If your question is a programming question, requiring knowledge of programming languages other than unix shell scripting languages, ask on Stack Overflow."

Comment: It's more of a question on using the compiler and linker than it is on programming.  The program it came from is just a container for the actual problem; that of using gets() under gcc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your assertion that fgets `just returns whatever will fit without any indication the string has been truncated` is obviously incorrect. If the character at the end of the input is not a newline and you have not reached the end of file then it is truncated. At this point you can allocate a bigger buffer, copy what you have so far into it and do another fgets.

What you seem to want is a function that reads an unlimited string. This means it will need to do memory allocation and therefor it will have a different signature than `gets(char *buffer)`, and you will need to free the result. This means that however much you don't want to change away from gets, you have no choice if you want to be able to handle arbitrary long lines.

This matches what the function [getline](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getline) does.

So replace

```
  char buffer[128];
  char *input=gets(buffer);
  /* do something with input or buffer */
```

with

```
  char *input=NULL;
  size_t len=0;
  getline(&input, &len, stdin);
  /* do something with input */
  free(input);
```

See the manual page for more details.

Comment: I knew about checking for newlines, and I have actually used that technique.  But it's awkward.  I was hoping for some sort of flag that says it was truncated.  But I do like the idea of a dynamically allocated buffer that gets copied to and re-allocated if it wasn't big enough.